# How to configure a query for document library search

Tags: sharepoint-online

**Background:**

In SP2013 Online, for every document library, we have a search box to search within the document library. The query returns results based on document metadata + match within the document.

**Requirement:**

Search result should match only from Document title and NOT within the document content.

**For e.g. :**

For the below-mentioned documents, if the search is keyed for word  “test”: 2 results are found.

1<sup>st</sup> with document title matching the query i.e. ‘Test.docx’ - REQUIRED

2<sup>nd</sup> – Document containing the query text – NOT REQUIRED

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve only document title using query

```
filename:test
```

Comment: I  have to configure the search for whole document library not for single document ,so how i can achieve that ?